# How to switch between dev and product environment on requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using requirejs as below. I am also using grunt uglify to turn my javascript into *.min.js format. In the dev environment, I should require the regular format of javascript source code; while on the product mode, I need to require *.min.js format. How to switch between two environment on requirejs?

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'public/js',
    paths: {
        angular: '/education/bower_components/angular/angular.min',
        app: 'app',
        'ui-router': '/education/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min',
        home: 'home',
        'angular-file-upload': '/education/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min',
        'angular-ui-date' : '/education/bower_components/angular-ui-date/src/date',
        'jquery-ui': '/education/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
        'angular-bootstrap': '/education/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min',
        'angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker':'/education/bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker/datetimepicker',
        'angular-bootstrap-tpls': '/education/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min',
        'angular-editor' : '/education/bower_components/angular-ueditor/dist/angular-ueditor.min',
        'ueditor-config' : '/education/bower_components/ueditor/ueditor.config',
        'ueditor-all' : '/education/bower_components/ueditor/ueditor.all',
        'angular-route': '/education/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
        'kindeditor' : '/education/bower_components/angular-kindeditor/kindeditor/kindeditor-all-min',
        'kindeditor-zh' : '/education/bower_components/angular-kindeditor/kindeditor/lang/zh-CN',
        'angular-kindeditor' : '/education/bower_components/angular-kindeditor/src/angular-kindeditor',
        'angular-datepicker' : '/education/bower_components/angular-datepicker/dist/angular-datepicker',
        'wx' : 'http://res.wx.qq.com/open/js/jweixin-1.0.0.js',
        'angular-animate': '/education/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min',
        'tweenmax': '/education/bower_components/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min',
        'jquery': '/education/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'ng-dialog': '/education/bower_components/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min',
        'hammerjs': '/education/bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.min',
        'angular-gestures': '/education/bower_components/angular-gestures/gestures.min',
        'bootstrap-carousel-swipe': '/education/bower_components/bootstrap-carousel-swipe/carousel-swipe',
        'bootstrap': '/education/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'
    }
```

Comment: `'angular-bootstrap'` and `'jquery'` are duplicated in your paths.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these issues. I will correct them.